# unity 3d 5 game crashes randomly on collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm having a problem with unity3d 5.1.1f1 physics2d.
I made a simple platformer where you fly around in a ufo and have to avoid hitting the walls. the walls sprite, which makes up the whole level, has a polygonCollider2d attached to it and the UFO (the player) had a circle and box colliders attached. everything works normally except every couple of minutes when you hit a wall the game seems to freeze. most of the time collisions work fine but every now and then they do this. It seems to be random as I cant find a pattern to reproduce the bug so to test it i just have to keep playing untill it decides to happen again. I used the profiler and pinpointed the bug to physics2D.fixedUpdate being the culprit. So my guess is that nothing in my scripts is causing it. oh and it happens on independent of platform. android build, windows build or in the unity editor is all the same. there must be something simple I'm missing.

here is the screenshot from the profiler when it happens. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iuZY.jpg

if I wait long enough it resolves the issue and the game continues smoothly and after a couple of minutes if may happen again. Any ideas? I've just started learning unity and this is bugging the hell out of me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is going to be really difficult (if not impossible) to resolve without seeing some actual code or at the very least your scene setup.

Comment: umm..are you following the rule of not sharing source-code?

Comment: This is basically al lthe code that has to do anything with collisions.
http://pastebin.com/j4bHFSVj
I'd show the scene setup but don't know how.

Comment: Also I noticed in the profiler when this bug happens in Physics2D.FixedUpdate i have Physics2DContactBeginAcquire and ContactPreSolveAcquire both with over 600 Calls. when the collision happens without the bug they have 2 Calls. I'm guessing the collision detection somehow gets looped. maybe colliders enter each other bounds and are continually colliding? I don't understand why this is not happening either all of the time or not at all :(

Comment: @VooGzy To me it sounds like alot of objects are colliding but nothing is being done to stop them from colliding I.E. can you maybe bounce them off of each other? Or maybe become solid objects so they can't move through each other?

Comment: Canvas yes that was the cause of the extreme slowdown which I thought was app freezing. but it is not the bug itself. The bug, which I haven't found the cause of yet, makes the player object jump to a seemingly random location on the map for no apparent reason after some collisions. this in turn causes all those collisions that slow the game down. Though I didn't solve the actual bug I managed a workaround where I disable physics on first impact of the player. After the collision the game reloads the level(scene). It kind of stops the 'freezing' even though it's not perfect. tnx for the help!